# Pass Text Value of cascading dropdown list item web controller

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I have a MVC web form that contains a couple textbox fields and two dropdown lists. I am trying to pass the text values of my dropdown list back to my controller to use within a method. The first dropdown list is for a location, is dependent on the second dropdown list (for security groups).

The only problem I am having is with the variable (var) value for userDn, I am trying to pass in the Location Name or "Text" value of the first dropdown list item but it is setting the location value to the switch case number of the associated with the dropdown list item instead:

Example: 
Firstname: Some
Lastname: Name
Location : Temecula  (switch case number 7)

currently returning: "CN=Some Name,OU=7,OU=Some OU,DC=xxx,DC=com

should return      : "CN=Some Name,OU=*Location Name*,OU=Some OU,DC=xxx,DC=com

Am I missing a function in my javascript that would return the Text value of my first dropdown list instead of the switch case number? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

```
public ActionResult AddUserToGroup()
    {
        var model = new CreateUser();
        List<SelectListItem> li = new List<SelectListItem>();
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Des Moines", Value = "1" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Fort Worth", Value = "2" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Kansas City", Value = "3" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Marysville", Value = "4" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "South Hack", Value = "5" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "St Clair", Value = "6" });
        li.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Temecula", Value = "7" });
        ViewData["location"] = li;

        return View(model);
    }


public JsonResult GetGroups(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> groups = new List<SelectListItem>();
        switch (id)
        {
            case "1":
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec 24-7 No Act", Value = "1" });
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec Admin", Value = "2" });
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec ExtAct-Front", Value = "3" });
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec ExtAct-Ship", Value = "4" });
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec ExtAct-Ship", Value = "5" });
                groups.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec Front Door Inner", Value = "6" });
                break;
        }
        return Json(new SelectList(groups, "Value", "Text"));
     }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult AddUserToGroup(CreateUser model)
    {
        var group = model.Group;
        var location = model.Location;
        var groupDn = "CN=" + group + ",OU=Groups,DC=xxx,DC=com";
        var user = model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName;
        var userDn = "CN=" + user + ",OU=" + location + ",OU=Some OU,DC=xxx,DC=com";

        try
        {
            DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://" + groupDn);
            entry.Properties["member"].Add(userDn);
            entry.CommitChanges();
            entry.Close();
        }
        catch(System.DirectoryServices.DirectoryServicesCOMException E)
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError("", "Exception adding cool user to additional group" + E);
        }
        var newUserAddition = model.FirstName + " " + model.LastName;
        var newGroupAddition = model.Group;

        return RedirectToAction("CompletedUserToGroup", "Users", new { someNewUserAddition = newUserAddition, someNewGroupAddition = newGroupAddition });
    }
```

--Below is the javascript in my view--

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {   
    $("#Location").change(function () {
        $("#Group").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetGroups")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#Location").val(), Text: $("#Location").val() },
            success: function (groups) {
                $.each(groups, function (i, group) {
                   // $("#Group").append('<option value="' + group.Value + '">' + group.Text + '</option>');
                    $("#Group").append('<option value="' + group.Text + '">' + group.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve states.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

Comment: Make the `Value` the same as `Text` instead of a number.

Comment: I tried that but it looks like for the location value, it is passing the case number (switch) of whatever location item I select. I do not know if that helps make this more clear.

Comment: When the form is submitted, it will send the selected optionv alue if that exist. Change the value to same as text and it will send you the text. `new SelectListItem { Text = "DM Genetec ExtAct-Front", Value = "DM Genetec ExtAct-Front" }`

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to pass in the value, it seems janky but it works, in my POST ActionResult I added the following (var locationValue) after initializing var location, then I changed var userDn to: "CN=" + user + ",OU=" + locationValue + ",OU=Some OU,DC=xxx,DC=com":

```
        var locationValue = "";
        if (location == "1")
        {
            locationValue = "Des Moines";
        }
        else if (location == "2")
        {
            locationValue = "Fort Worth";
        }
        else if (location == "3")
        {
            locationValue = "Kansas City";
        }
        else if (location == "4")
        {
            locationValue = "Marysville";
        }
        else if (location == "5")
        {
            locationValue = "South Hack";
        }
        else if (location == "6")
        {
            locationValue = "St Clair";
        }
        else if (location == "7")
        {
            locationValue = "Temecula";
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't care about the integer value, then change `Value` to be the same as `Text`.

```
new SelectListItem { Text = "Des Moines", Value = "Des Moines" }
```

If you don't want to change the `Value`, then you can obtain the text label from the selected child `<option>`.

```
$("#Location option:selected").text()
```

The value from `$("#Location").val()` is automatic but the text requires finding the right child option.